# Jquery get value from within dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page that has a drop down menu and a div underneath. Depending on what you pick from the menu, that determines what loads in the div. I need the dynamically called content within the div to be able to know what menu value was chosen. It also need to be able to retrieve other drop down menu values that can change while the dynamic content is loaded.

Once a submit button is clicked from within the dynamic content area all of these values need to be grabbed. I am trying to use .parent() from jquery but I have a feeling that wont work as I haven't been able to get it working yet.

Any advice and help on how to obtain input fields values from external dynamically loaded content would be much appreciated.

This is the Jquery and Html from the main page:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#men2link").click(function(){
         $.ajax({ url: 'pages/abc.php', success: function(html) {
            $("#subajax-content").empty().append(html);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

<table>
    <tr>
      <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Menu 1:</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="men1" id="men1">
                            <option>Select Option</option>
                            <option value="o1">option1</option>
                            <option value="o2">option2</option>
                            <option value="o3">option3</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="men2link">Menu 2</td>
                    <td>        
                        <select name="men2" id="men2">
                            <option>Select Option</option>
                            <option value="r">Received</option>
                            <option value="nr">Not Received</option>
                            <option value="na">Not Applicable</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
      </td>
      <td class="align-top"><div id="subajax-content"></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Html & JQuery that is loaded dynamically into subajax-content div

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#save").click(function(){
       alert($("#home").parent("#men2").val());
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Need to see HTML and the javascript/jQuery you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "closest()" instead of parent() as it is not that strict

Answer (score 0):

First, make the outer table identifiable. For a sole table you can use an id or for repeating tables, use a class:

```
<table id="outerTable">
<!-- or -->
<table class="outerTable">
```

Now you need just one block of jQuery. This will responsive to the dynamically inserted content so there's no need to deliver any more javascript/jQuery with the content.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //This part is unchanged
    $("#men2link").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'pages/abc.php', 
            success: function(html) {
                $("#subajax-content").empty().append(html);
            }
        });
    });

    //This part is a modified version of what was previously delivered with the dynamic content
    //For use with id="outerTable"
    $("#outerTable").on('click', "#save", function() {
        var $outerTable = $(this).closest(".outerTable"),
            val1 = $outerTable.find("#men1").val(),
            val2 = $outerTable.find("#men2").val();
        alert([val1, val2]);
    });
});
```

Notes:

- The code will be slightly different for repeating outer tables each with its own inner table.
- The code will be slightly different for repeating inner tables within a sole outer table.
- With repeating outer tables or repeating inner tables, the select menus and save buttons should also have classes rather than ids.